# Recurring payment for paypal - android

Tags: android, paypal, payment, recurring

I need to add Paypal recurring payment option in Android application.

I googled and can't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal has an solution for subscriptions and recurring payments. https://www.paypal.com/pdn-recurring.

The technical part is based on a web application. But the same POST Request can be made in android. An example can be found here: http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Answer (score 0):

With credit cards you can tokenize a credit card using the mobile SDK and make payments with it in the future.

For PayPal accounts you can use future payments: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/make-future-payment/